# How to skip a column using txt2mat

Tags: matlab

I´m trying to import some csv files in matlab, but csvread is too slow.

I´m using txt2mat, but i don´t know how to skip the first column in the import.

This is the way im trying

```
    myimportedfile = txt2mat(myfile,'ReadMode','block',1) %im skipping the headers too.
```

The reason i need to skip is beacause the first column is non-numerical data.

Is there a way to do this with txt2mat or is there a better way?

Tks in advance.

Comment: `txt2mat`help gives "it quickly converts ascii files containing m-by-n numeric data". This doesn't apply to your case. Why not `textscan`?

Comment: `dlmread` might be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**textscan** gives you the ability to skip columns. It reads in data using an **fprintf**-like format string.

Example file:

```
Val1 Val2 Val3
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

Code:

```
tmp = textscan('example.txt', '%i %*i %i') % the * indicates fields to ignore
tmp{:}
```

Comment: SO in this case txtscan will ignore the second column?

Comment: Right. The * indicates fields that should be skipped. So, in this example, the format says "match an integer field, match another integer (but ignore it), and then match one more integer field." textscan does this for each line, and returns the fields matched in cell arrays (one array for each field).

Comment: Gordon, 

    Now everything is clear and I was able to make my code work.

Thank you very much!