# Load multiple tab delimited text files

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have boatloads of tab delimited textfiles that contain numerical data in 1000x2 format.
They're named file00001.txt - file10000.txt

I would like to write a script to load each of these files and make a variable containing ONLY the 400th row of the 2nd column of each of these files.

After that I'm going to try and plot a graph with the data I collected - but that's not important here.

I would be very grateful for your help.

Edit -

My most recent endeavour is:

```
numfiles = 10;
mydata = cell(1, numfiles);

for k = 1:numfiles
  myfilename = sprintf('DM0000%d.txt', k);
  mydata{k} = importdata(myfilename);
end
```

I'm running into a few problems -
1) if numfiles is >9, the 10th file data entry in the mydata variable comes up as []. This may have something to do with the naming method of my files? They're named in this fashion:
DM00000 ...DM00009, DM00010, DM00011, etc.

2) Also this is pretty slow to load, someone said using fopen, if so where should I put it in and how?

I'm guessing it'd be somewhere along the lines of fopen('filename', 'r')?

Comment: You may to check with the postings at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368164/how-to-skip-a-column-using-txt2mat

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For a question on Stack Overflow it is expected that you describe your own attempts to answer the question, and state where you got stuck.

Comment: Check out [eval](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) and [tdfread](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/tdfread.html), or [textscan](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368164/how-to-skip-a-column-using-txt2mat). Combine it with a loop, and you should be well on your way. Try some, and come back with details if you can't make it work. Good luck!

Comment: @RobertP.: I don't see a reason to use `eval` in this case. If possible `eval` should be avoided.

Comment: @user3053401: If you are using matlab on a windows machine with excel installed, try `xlsread` with `xlRange`-Parameter

Comment: I just updated the my post!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, this is what I'd recommend:

```
numfiles = 10;
row = 400;
column = 2;

data = zeros(1, numfiles);

for k = 1:numfiles
   filename = sprintf('DM%05d.txt', k);
   fid = fopen(filename,'r');
   tempdata = textscan(fid, '%f%f');
   fclose(fid);
   data(k) = tempdata{column}(row);
end
```

I've updated the `formatspec` in `sprintf` to create the filenames correctly (you were missing the padding with zeros). I'm using `textscan` to import the data as doubles (change the `%f` to something else if required - check out the formatspec documentation). I also changed `data` to be a matrix rather than a cell array. You mentioned that you'd want to plot the data, so it'll be easier if it's a matrix and I couldn't see any need to use a cell array here.